# Adding empty line between each file when using lapply

Tags: r, csv, merge

I need to merge all the csv files in a folder into one csv file. However I need a empty row between each of the file's contents in the merged CSV file. This is to help differentiate the different files and put into the correct formatting for later. Below I have attached the working code that merges the files using lapply, and I would appreciate any ideas on how I can modify this code to add in an empty line before each merge. Thanks.

```
    filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE)
    Combined <- lapply(filenames,function(x){
    read.csv(x, header=FALSE)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add a row of NA values at the end of each dataframe before you `rbind` the dataframes together.

For example:

```
All <- lapply(filenames,function(i){
    dat = read.csv(i, header=FALSE)
    dat[nrow(dat)+1,] = NA
    return(dat)
    })
```

Comment: If `All` is a list, how is `nrow` supposed to work on it? This will error with `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`. (I think it'll be fine if you do that `NA` assignment within the `lapply` before returning.)

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks. I updated my answer with the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a blank (`NA`) row to each frame before writing:

```r
list_of_frames <- list(head(mtcars, 3), head(mtcars, 2))
lapply(list_of_frames, function(x) { x[nrow(x)+1,] <- NA; x})
# [[1]]
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4               NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# [[2]]
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3              NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: When I tried this I got the error "Error in x[nrow(x) + 1, ] <- NA : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

Comment: No idea, Dg1, it works as posted. Are you starting with an actual list of data frames?